# Better Architecture for .Net Performance : Caching, Serializing or Writing to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

After having hard times with performance in my winform app, I decided to redesign it to separate the processing step from the visual reporting step.
As a picture is worth a thousand words, I drew this for the purpose of this question :

[image: Redesign]

Needless to say that Computing/Visualisation layers were separated, but the problem with the first configuration was that the amount of Data that was stored in live memory to be displayed on the flow was growing, growing, taking more and more RAM space, which resulted in the computing part to be squeezed up and taking longer and longer (linearly in time)

That's why I came up with the new design. Now this proved to be helpful and efficient : Processing first, using 100% memory to compute, and then only handling stored results to be displayed ( *A la* "generate report" button)

SO here is my simple question : What are my options for that, and which are most performance-friendly, (Caching, Serializing, Storing in files then reading them back, Lazy-Loading....)

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

Data is formed of simple and plain line records (actually times series) that could be stored in CSV format for example

Comment: That depends entirely on what the data looks like... can you describe the nature of the data? for example, by "lazy loading", do you mean there are lots of sequential records but you only need one at a time? or do you mean lazy-loading inside objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the edit, it sounds like the data is pretty simple flat records. Since the volume is high, I would probably look at file-based storage - so it then becomes a matter of format. CSV/TSV is pretty easy to write, and with suitable *streaming* readers (like [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx)) you won't have to buffer all the data in memory first. Of course, if your displays *need* all the data in memory, that goes out the window.

For large volume, sheer bandwidth becomes the main bottleneck, plus processing time. CSV and friends typically compress (gzip etc) very nicely, but take CPU. Personally, I'm a long-time fan of "protocol buffers", and it would seem a nice fit here - it is well-suited to streaming access, is low bandwidth, and is binary  - you get the benefits of smaller IO costs without the CPU overhead of compression. Plus it is more object-based, so it is easier to apply to your existing data without any extra interpretation steps.

I'm not *entirely* sure if I'm answering the same question you're asking - so I'll stop there - but please feel free to clarify anything I've got horribly wrong.

---

Here's a basic test rig to show some typical usages of the two methods discussed above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using ProtoBuf;
static class Program {

    static void Main() {
        var rand = new Random(123456);
        var timeOrigin = new DateTime(2010,1,1);
        Serializer.PrepareSerializer<MyFunRecord>();
        Console.WriteLine("Writing .proto ...");
        const int LOOP = 500000;
        using (var file = File.Create("raw.data"))
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            double total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
            {
                var obj = new MyFunRecord();
                obj.Id = i;
                obj.Count = rand.Next(500);
                obj.Value = rand.NextDouble() * 4000;
                obj.When = timeOrigin.AddDays(rand.Next(1000));
                obj.Name = RandomString(rand);
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(file, obj, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag);
                total += obj.Value;
            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(file.Length / (1024 * 1024)+ "MB");
            Console.WriteLine(total + " (check)");
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        }
        rand = new Random(123456);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Writing tsv ...");
        using (var file = File.Create("raw.tsv"))
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(file))
            {
                var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                double total = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
                {
                    var obj = new MyFunRecord();
                    obj.Id = i;
                    obj.Count = rand.Next(500);
                    obj.Value = rand.NextDouble() * 4000;
                    obj.When = timeOrigin.AddDays(rand.Next(1000));
                    obj.Name = RandomString(rand);

                    Write(writer, obj);

                    total += obj.Value;
                }
                watch.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(file.Length / (1024 * 1024) + "MB");
                Console.WriteLine(total + " (check)");
                Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Reading .proto ...");
        using(var file = File.OpenRead("raw.data"))
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            double total = 0;
            foreach (var obj in Serializer.DeserializeItems<MyFunRecord>(file, PrefixStyle.Base128, Serializer.ListItemTag))
            {
                total += obj.Value;

            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(total + " (check again)");
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Reading tsv ...");
        using (var file = File.OpenRead("raw.tsv"))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            double total = 0;
            foreach (var obj in Read(reader))
            {
                total += obj.Value;

            }
            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(total + " (check again)");
            Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms");
        }



    }

    private static void Write(TextWriter writer, MyFunRecord obj)
    {
        writer.Write(obj.Id);
        writer.Write('\t');
        writer.Write(obj.Name);
        writer.Write('\t');
        writer.Write(obj.When);
        writer.Write('\t');
        writer.Write(obj.Value);
        writer.Write('\t');
        writer.Write(obj.Count);
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
    private static IEnumerable<MyFunRecord> Read(TextReader reader)
    {
        string line;
        char[] delim = new[] { '\t' };
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(delim);
            var obj = new MyFunRecord();
            obj.Id = int.Parse(parts[0]);
            obj.Name = parts[1];
            obj.When = DateTime.Parse(parts[2]);
            obj.Value = double.Parse(parts[3]);
            obj.Count = int.Parse(parts[4]);
            yield return obj;
        }

    }
    static string RandomString(Random rand)
    {
        int len = rand.Next(1, 20);
        var sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            sb.Append('a' + rand.Next(26));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

}
[ProtoContract]
class MyFunRecord
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]public int Id { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)] public DateTime When { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4)] public double Value { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(5)] public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestions totally makes sense. Never heard of protobuf, though... Your .Net implementation of it seems convenient. However, I have no network issue (well not yet) as the application is a desktop app. So I still wonder which would perform best in my case (CSV or Serialization)

Comment: @Mark: Off-Topic : How is it possible to earn 100K points per year without fully  dedicating your time to SOF ? :-D

Comment: @Mika - well, we can test it... 2 seconds